# Browser height in css file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, height

I'm not sure how I should go about using Javascript or perhaps a jQuery library to obtain the browser height and then pass it to a variable to use in my external CSS file?

Comment: with css is impossible to get `height()` of window for example. Definitely does not. You must use some scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(document).height()` to find the height of the total document.

You can use `$(window).height()` to find the height of the viewport

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use JavaScript, how about media-queries?

```
media screen and (min-height:700px){
   /* Specific styles... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to dynamically pass anything to CSS. Instead you should design your CSS to be responsive to varying document heights.

Answer (score 1):

To get the height and the width of the client dynamically use javascript and then set the height and the width of the objects dynamically. You can use the following javascript example to get the height and the width of the client.As it depends upon the browsers you are using.
to get the height and the width of the client try this javascript:

> var myWidth; var myHeight;
>
> if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
>
> //Non-IE
>
> myWidth = window.innerWidth; myHeight = window.innerHeight;
>
> } else if( document.documentElement &&
>
> ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
>   document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
>
> //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
>
> myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;  myHeight =
>   document.documentElement.clientHeight;
>
> } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth ||
>   document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
>
> //IE 4 compatible
>
> myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;  myHeight =
>   document.body.clientHeight;
>
> }